# Is my plan to repair a broken primary septic drain pipe reasonable?

Tags: plumbing, septic

I bought a house a few years ago and it appears as though the previous owner knew the septic pipe was leaking where it leaves the house and goes to the septic tank. There’s about a tube’s worth of caulk where the pipe meets the foundation in the basement. I have a poo bucket that catches the slow drip and I have to empty it every few weeks. I also had the outside of the basement re-waterproofed a few years ago so I’m confident this is isolated to the septic pipe.

I’ve dug out the pipe on the outside about 3-4 ft and couldn’t find a leak on the outside so I’m guessing the leak is in the pipe between my foundation. I suspect the pipe elbow.

Is it feasible for a general novice like myself to replace the pipe? I’m thinking about cutting 1 ft above the clean out in the basement and maybe 1-2 ft on the outside. Saw them bad boys off, replace with new septic pipes, epoxy together, and Bob’s your uncle?

Anything I’m not thinking of? Pitfalls to avoid? 100% call a plumber? I really enjoy doing home projects myself because of the satisfaction of learning something, researching, and accomplishing the task.

Appreciate everyone’s time and advice!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your primary question was subjective and not for us to answer, so I revised your title. Please take the [tour] and see the [help]. Questions should be technical in nature.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look difficult, but if it turns out to be difficult, then you're going to spending some time in the bushes and/or gas station while you sort it out. Use ABS glue, not epoxy.

As a preliminary step, you should widen the hole in the wall so that you can get hydraulic cement at least 3" deep into the wall around the pipe. Get at least 1-1/2" depth of the concrete clean of silicone and...residue...for bonding with the hydraulic cement.

It's metal pipe for which the IPC requires shielding from concrete and cinder block, so technically you don't need anything to protect the ABS pipe under an IPC jurisdiction. The UPC requires sleeving for any pipe passing through concrete. Abrasion from the wall was the most likely cause of the current failure, so do the sleeving regardless.

Roof paper is commonly used for sleeving. Alternatively you might buy a no-hub ("Fernco") coupler to put around the outside of the pipe for abrasion protection from the wall. A sheet of neoprene would work well. Whatever you use, seal it against the circumference of the pipe (using a hose clamp or two with a no-hub coupler or using silicone caulk with roof paper or a neoprene sheet). From the inside you'll want to fill between the wall and the sleeve with hydraulic cement, and from the outside you'll want to fill the gap with a durable sealant (I'd just use silicone).

The second most likely cause of the failure was poorly done backfilling. When you backfill, you should take care to get a nice stiff bed of soil below the pipe so that settlement doesn't stress the pipe where it exits the wall. Wait until after backfilling to fill the joint around the ABS in the wall with hydraulic cement. Soaking sand with water applies the most weight that the sand will probably ever experience and lubricates the soil particles, so that can be a good strategy for compacting sandy fill.

And if you intend to use mechanical couplers like no-hub couplers, read up on your local code--allowing their use varies widely from city to city. It's best to use ABS glue everywhere if you can.

Comment: "Fernco" doesn't translate well in a global sense (and isn't intuitive in general). I would advise using a shielded (metal-wrapped) no-hub coupler and not just a cheap rubber one. This application is too important and you don't want to have to get in there again if it fails.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see from the well-versed individuals above, the answer in short is--call the septic crew to repair it.

It's a bigger job than you think it is. I enjoy projects as well, but I also know what my wheelhouse is.

Aside from that,  if you ever choose to sell your house, you will have a 99.9% chance of running into an issue with a buyer once the septic tank inspector comes and points out the work you did without any permits or use of professionals. If I were the potential buyer, I would certainly be requesting a brand new septic tank, pipes, and leach field if I were to buy the house.

Take this one on the chin and hire professionals.